# Excel =TTEST and Data Analysis ToolPak give different p-values for t-test

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

I'm trying to perform a t-test on the two pairs of means you can see in the image below - blue vs red, two tailed, unpaired with unequal variance.

As you can see, the p-value returned by the Data Analysis ToolPak is different from the one returned by the =TTEST function. Does anyone have any insight into why this may be? They should both return the same value

In the second image, for a different dataset, you can see the p-value returned by the Data Analysis tool is different from the heteroscedastic =TTEST, but identical to the homoscedastic one, despite the fact that the Data Analysis tool was configured for unequal variance.

Could someone please assist with this? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your t-test formula uses 2 which is the two-sample equal variance (homoscedastic), and the one you selected for the data analysis is the two-sample unequal variance (heteroscedastic). Try either using 3 instead of 2 in your formula, or running the data analysis using the selection for the the equal variance.

[Here is the MSFT Page regarding the T-test formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/t-test-function-d4e08ec3-c545-485f-962e-276f7cbed055)

Comment: The formula is heteroscedastic (3 at the end), the 2 is to signify a two-tailed test.