# TTEST and Data Analysis ToolPak give different p-values for t-test

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78117303/excel-ttest-and-data-analysis-toolpak-give-different-p-values-for-t-test) was incorrectly closed, so I made a new post as I am unable to reopen it.

I'm trying to perform a t-test on the two pairs of means you can see in the images below - blue vs red, two tailed, unpaired with unequal variance.

As you can see, the p-value returned by the Data Analysis ToolPak is different from the one returned by the =TTEST function, even though they are both configured to perform the same statistical test.
[image]

In the second image, for a different dataset, you can see the p-value returned by the Data Analysis tool is different from the heteroscedastic =TTEST, but identical to the homoscedastic one, despite the fact that the Data Analysis tool was configured for unequal variance.

Could someone please help me understand where the difference lies? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an excerpt from Microsoft support regarding the difference. It has to do with the degree of freedom which is rounded by the analysis toolpak but not rounded by the ttest/t.test function. I don't have a better explanation, but have poked around and confirmed this is the case from your data and what's been said online. Ttest is likely more accurate from this basis.

"This analysis tool performs a two-sample student's t-Test. This t-Test form assumes that the two data sets came from distributions with unequal variances. It is referred to as a heteroscedastic t-Test. As with the preceding Equal Variances case, you can use this t-Test to determine whether the two samples are likely to have come from distributions with equal population means. Use this test when there are distinct subjects in the two samples. Use the Paired test, described in the follow example, when there is a single set of subjects and the two samples represent measurements for each subject before and after a treatment.

The following formula is used to determine the statistic value t.

The following formula is used to calculate the degrees of freedom, df. Because the result of the calculation is usually not an integer, the value of df is rounded to the nearest integer to obtain a critical value from the t table. **The Excel worksheet function T.TEST uses the calculated df value without rounding, because it is possible to compute a value for T.TEST with a noninteger df. Because of these different approaches to determining the degrees of freedom, the results of T.TEST and this t-Test tool will differ in the Unequal Variances case**."

[Here is the link to the page explaining it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-analysis-toolpak-to-perform-complex-data-analysis-6c67ccf0-f4a9-487c-8dec-bdb5a2cefab6?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xladdin.chm1780&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)